# Prove a mapping $C(X,Y)\to \operatorname{Hom}(C(Y), C(X))$ is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces, and let $F$ be a continuous function from $X$ to $Y$.

Define a function $\Phi_F$ from $C(Y)$ to $C(X)$ by $\Phi_F(f)=f\circ F.$

I have shown $\Phi_F$ is a unital $*$-homomorphism from $C(Y)$ to $C(X)$, where $*$ is the usual complex conjugation of complex-valued functions and it is naturally an involution. (i.e. I proved that $\Phi_F$ is an algebra homomorphism that carries identity element to identity element, and respects complex conjugation)

**Now the problem is to prove that the mapping $F\mapsto \Phi_F$ is a bijection between the set of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ and the set of unital $*$-homomorphism from $C(Y)$ to $C(X)$.**

The fact that this mapping is injective is trivial. But I can not figure out the surjective part. Can someone help me? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know about the homeomorphism $X\to \mathcal M(C(X))$, where $\mathcal M(A)$ is the set of non-zero homomorphisms $A\to\mathbb C$ and the map takes $x\in X$ to the evaluation map $\phi_x\colon C(X)\to X$?

Comment: @Christoph Yeah, I know this result. And should it be $\phi_x: C(X) \to \mathbb C$?

Comment: Yes, of course. Now a homomorphism $\Phi\colon C(Y)\to C(X)$ induces a homomorphism $\mathcal M(C(X))\to\mathcal M(C(Y))$ which translates back to a continuous map $F\colon C(X)\to C(Y)$ that satisfies $\Phi_F=\Phi$.

Comment: @Christoph I can understand your argument, but when I try to write down the explicit correspondence(i.e. translating back and the induced homomorphism) I fail. Could you write it out explicitly? Thank you so much.